# Stop metthod of AxShockwaveFlash com component thorws Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: winforms, flash, winforms-interop

I'm using AxShockwaveFlash  com component to show a flash file in windows application.

, I call the method Stop() to stop that flash.

But some of the users, its throwing the exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory,This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt ".

Please let me know why this is happening for few users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure windows-form embedded Flash content requires the same as JavaScript & HTML implementation, but usually you would only expose the essential methods for your Flash movie through the ExternalInterface class (in AS3 that is).

Basically you use ExternalInterface to enable which methods can be accessed from its outside container.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running your application as "run as administrator" check if it throws an error then.